# No electricity but have a Ford Econoline van with a 12v Auxiliary "Power Point" Outlet (and more)

Tags: voltage

I'm trying to figure out if I can get power to my desktop PC from a source other than electrical. I know *nothing* about electricity. I have the following:

- 12v Auxiliary "Power Point" Outlet in my van
- APC Back-Up UPS XS Series, 1500 VA, 865 WATT

I actually forgot I had the UPS, so basically what I have are empty batteries: I would need to recharge the UPS in some alternative way that is not electric. Thanks.

Comment: If your desktop PC is like every other one that I have seen, the only way to power it, is with electricity. So, that's a dead end question. If you are asking how to charge your batteries other then plugging them into the wall, that is another question. Can you please verify what you are asking?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Yes Tyler, the UPS backup would then be the method I would like help with.

Comment: You will need some source of electricity to charge batteries or run a computer - a portable generator driven by a gas or diesel engine may be a solution.

Comment: The UPS probably has a 12V lead-acid battery in it, just like the van does. (the big one under the hood) So in theory at least, the van can charge it directly, and then you can put it back in the UPS and run the PC. Just DON'T BE TEMPTED TO RUN THE UPS WITH AN EXPOSED BATTERY!!! I did that in college with a different project (PC for machine vision on a metal-framed home-built go-kart), and realized later that I had created a blatantly exposed, unmarked, easy-to-grab 120V shock hazard in the shop. (The entire 'kart was live, via the UPS's exposed battery) I'm surprised they never called me out.

Comment: Thank you AaronD. This the question I posed to Peter; I'm clarifying it right now . . .

Answer (score 1):

You can get inverters that will connect to your vehicle's 12 volt battery, and produce "household-style" 120V AC.  Low-power inverters, up to about 200 watts, can plug into the "power point" or lighter outlet.  Higher power inverters must be wired more directly to the vehicle battery.

Beware when running an inverter from the vehicle battery that you don't run the battery down so far that you can't start the engine!!

Your APC UPS, if charged via an inverter or from "shore power" (home power outlet) could run your PC for an hour or two, depending on the actual power requirement of the PC.

Edit, to repond to the OP's questions...

Your APC UPS is intended to plug into a normal AC outlet, and will normally pass the AC power from that outlet to any loads you plug into it, while also charging its batteries - no additional batteries are required.

If you have no AC power avaialble, and need to run AC-powered equipment from your vehicle, you will need a 12 Volt DC -> 120V AC inverter to produce the required AC from you vehicle's battery.  I suggest that you add a separate "house" battery to prevent discharging your vehicle battery.  This house battery would be connected to the vehicle battery through a "battery combiner" so that it would be charged, along with the vehicle battery, when the engine is running, but disconnected from the vehicle battery when it is not.

You would then connect an inverter to the "house" battery to provide the AC that your computer requires.

Jumper cables should only be used for very temporary connections - if you are making a permanent installation, you should use proper large cables with suitable terminal lugs, bolted to the battery and inverter.

Small inverters, rated for 250 watts or less, my be plugged into a lighter outlet ("power point" now, since smoking is discouraged.)

Comment: Okay Peter, good info. Is there any way I can monitor how much my battery is being drained so I can be alerted before it's drained? It kills me that I have a very good battery restarter for the van but it needs (you guessed it) electricity.

Comment: There are battery monitors that will show the charge level of the battery.  Another (perhaps better)  solution is to have two batteries - the existing vehicle battery is only used for normal vehicle loads, and a second "house" battery is used for the inverter and other non-vehicle loads.  A battery combiner will connect the house and start batteries while the engine is running, so both batteries are charged, then separate the batteries when the engine is stopped.  Look for information on boat and RV electrical systems.

Comment: Wow. A second battery. Didn't even think of that, thanks Peter. Er, where/how/what would I place it in/on/under? Kind of unnerving having battery acid in the house. Ideas? Also, what do you think of Tyler's suggestion? Could I get this to work with a UPS?

Comment: AND ... how would it connect to the computer? or to the UPS?

Comment: Assuming that the PC and UPS need AC power, you would connect an inverter to the "house" battery, and plug your PC and UPS into that.  It may be more efficient to use a notebook computer rather than a desktop, and perhaps find a 12 volt power supply for it, rather than the usual AC supply - this would avoid (or at least reduce) inevitable power losses in the DC->AC>DC conversions.

Comment: Peter I'm going to reword my prior comment having to do with connecting (and remember, I know zero about electricity).

Comment: Peter I'm going to reword my prior comment having to do with connecting (and remember, I know zero about electricity). You'll need to define this visually for me because I have no idea what these connections mean! **1**) I have this _really heavy_ UPC with USB connections and a Serial Port; **2**) I have a battery under the hood of my van, **3**) I've purchased a _second_ car battery and it is in the house. How do I get my UPC's batteries fully charged? what plugs into the van's battery? what plugs into the house battery? what plugs into the UPS? Are jumper cables used anywhere in this? Thanks

Comment: Ideally, the second battery I suggested would be a "deep cycle" type - often called "Marine" or "RV (Recreation vehicle)" battery.  They withstand frequent deep discharges much better than a common starting battery.  From your questions, I strongly suggest you look for someone with marine or RV electrical systems experience. Also, what you do may depend on whether this is required for a few days, or is a long-term requirement.  For long-term use, a portable or fixed gas-driven generator may be the best solution.

Comment: Peter I'm trying to get a visual concept, not products. A connects to C using (eg. jumper cables) ... B connects to E using (eg. USB).  **Generic hardware descriptions**, that's all. What does the setup look like, without brands etc.?